# Error trying to use GSON with own class

Tags: java, android, gson, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use Google's GSON for the first time in my Android app. I want to use GSON with a class called `UserValues`, which keeps most of my ArrayList, booleans, Strings and other basic objects in one place. My goal is to save an instance of `UserValues` into `SharedPreferences`. I wrote:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        String userValuesJSON=gson.toJson(userValues);
        getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("JSON", userValuesJSON).commit();
```

The error I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make method constructor accessible
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:336)
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:97)
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:79)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:71)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
```

when I added GSON I added the following to `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {   
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Any brainstorming greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is how the constructor looks like:

```
public class UserValues implements Serializable {

    private Integer period;
    private Float fee;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> theBooleans = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> theIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<String> theIntegerKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ArrayList<String> theBooleanKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String myAppKey = "Investor Playground";
    private static final ArrayList<Integer> theIntDefValues = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Float> arrayList;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> theDates;
    private ArrayList<Float> strategyResult;
    private int theCurrentFragment;

    private int theCurrentGraph;

    Context context;


    public UserValues(Context context_) {
        context=context_;
    ...

    }
```

Comment: The error would suggest that the default constructor of UserValues (`public UserValues () {}`) is not accessible. This is either because one does not exist, or it is marked as private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an empty constructor to the class
as this will only be used to set values this should not cause any issues if the context is not initialised

```
public UserValues() {

}
```

Comment: As soon as I took away the context in my UserValues class, GSON worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `UsersValues` class must have a public empty parameter constructor to be used with gson.

Answer (score 0):

Add empty constructor to your class definition

```
public UserValues() {}
```

also you can't have Context as a variable if you want to use Gson

Answer (score 0):

It's passed a long time of this topic, but for others I say.
If you have View class in your model! the Gson can not convert it to json and throws **java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make method constructor accessible**....

I fixed my problem by deleting View feild from my model.